# Argument Passed is not complete in C++

Tags: c++, wpf, vb.net, window

I am just trying to pass an argument to another Application using `CreateProcess`.
When i get the argument in the destination, It not full only a part is passed. The output I am getting is `"1\\Documentation\\U3DElements.pdf"`

**This the Code that passes the Argument.(This is a C++ Code)**

```
STARTUPINFO si;     
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

// set the size of the structures
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
LPTSTR cmdArgs = "C:\\Users\\vignesh.d\\Downloads\\sdk110_v1_win\\Adobe\\Acrobat XI SDK\\Version1\\Documentation\\U3DElements.pdf";
// start the program up
if (CreateProcess(
        TEXT("C:\\Users\\vignesh.d\\Documents\\Visual Studio  2012\\Projects\\AdobePlugin\\AdobePlugin\\bin\\Debug\\AdobePlugin.exe"),
        cmdArgs,NULL,NULL,FALSE,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &si,
        &pi))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
}
CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

**This the Code where I display it.(AdobePlugin.exe This is a VB Code)**

```
Private Sub App_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As StartupEventArgs)
    MsgBox(e.Args(2))
End Sub
```

I want the MsgBox to display The Full Code "C:\Users\vignesh.d\Downloads\sdk110_v1_win\Adobe\Acrobat XI SDK\Version1\Documentation\U3DElements.pdf"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters/Arguments are separated a space character.

```
MsgBox(e.Args(1))
```

Would give you the first half of your argument.

If you want to pass something containing a space as one parameter, you'll need to put it in quotes, likes this:

```
LPTSTR cmdArgs = "\"C:\\Users\\vignesh.d\\Downloads\\sdk110_v1_win\\Adobe\\Acrobat XI SDK\\Version1\\Documentation\\U3DElements.pdf\"";
```

It can't hurt to quote the parameters whether they contain a space or not.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. But to my knowledge there is not escape sequence for space. Why would you need that?

Comment: While sending path, If the path has spaces then the path is spitted into two argument. That's why I asked. Its not a problem now i have corrected it by replacing with a definite code for space i replaced it as %20 and encrypted it and decrypted it in the receiving application to get the full path...

Comment: As I stated in the answer: You should put the argument "in quotes"